# JointJs - event onConnect Link

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I am trying to create a board where an user can dynamically add blocks and connect the blocks with links. (Something like [this](http://jointjs.com/demos/fsa) but dynamically)
I'm using JointJs framework and till now everything is working as expected, but I need to show some info when the user connect two blocks. 
My problem is that **I cant find an event to handle when connecting the blocks**.

I looked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769850/changesource-event-in-jointjs) but in my example I do not have the link instance to attach the event.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/148e2f6s/3/) you can see my example

And here is how the block are added to the board. the **magnet: true** in the text property is what makes the text connectable. I really need some help finding an event to handle when the link is connected.

```
 var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.newRect({
     position: { x: position, y: position },
     size: { width: 100, height: 40 },
     attrs: {
         rect: { 'stroke-width': '1',  stroke: 'black', rx: 3, ry: 3, fill: 'blue'},
         text: { text: 'Block', magnet: true,  }
     }
 });
 graph.addCell(rect);
```

I also looked to the mouseUp event and coordinates but came out with nothing..
I really appreciate some help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `change:source` and `change:target` events (as the all other events triggered by cell models) propagate to the graph so you don't need a reference to your links, you can do something like:

```
graph.on('change:source change:target', function(link) {
    if (link.get('source').id && link.get('target').id) {
        // both ends of the link are connected.
    }
})
```

Comment: Does it exist a way to avoid link without target node?

Comment: dave, this will only fire when a connection is fully made, but not when one end of it is cut. What is the proper way of getting an event when a connection is made or lost, but *not* if an open end is just moved (as it would be the case with `change:source` unfiltered).

Comment: You can react on paper.on('cell:pointerup blank:pointerup', handler) where you discard all links that do not have both source.id and target.id set.